# What do you call a bijection that must preserve the order of its mappings?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

A **bijection** is an **injective** *and* **surjective** function, as such:

[image]

But the following is also a bijective function:

[image]

This means there is a further restriction that could be added to the definition of a function, and that is one where "no crisscrossing of lines is allowed." This is what I mean when I say "a bijection that must preserve the order of its mappings."

Is there a category or name for such a restricted relationships between sets and/or categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called an increasing (or less ambiguously: [order-preserving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#In_order_theory)) bijection. Note that it is not necessarily an [isomorphism of ordered sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_isomorphism). It is however if its domain is totally ordered.